# Script works only when run in cuda-memcheck

Tags: torch, cudnn, cuda-gdb

I'm writing a convnet using torch and cudnn and having some memory issues.
I tried debugging the script with cuda-memcheck only to notice it actually runs when fed through cuda-memcheck (albeit slower than it should).

Turns out if cuda-memcheck is running in the background, a separate instantiation of the script itself also runs fine.

Any idea what might be happening here?

Comment: Have you tried running [this](https://github.com/soumith/cudnn.torch)? You should provide some more information about your "memory issues" and how you are using Torch.

Comment: @Haggis this was a bug in NVIDIA Cudnn R2 release candidate 1. It has since been fixed in Cudnn R2 - rc2.